# With multiple related authors, how to display only one when joining on tables

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to return a result set listing all books with a column including the first author (alphabetically for each book).

I've got a SQL query that returns all books, joins on author and orders by book author name but this falls over when I then try to group by book ID to remove duplicates...

```
SELECT
  ct.entry_id AS SKU,
  c.channel_title,
  ct.title, ct.status,
  bat.title AS author_title
FROM exp_store_products sp
JOIN exp_channel_titles ct ON ct.entry_id=sp.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channels c ON c.channel_id=ct.channel_id
LEFT JOIN exp_playa_relationships pl ON pl.parent_entry_id=ct.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles bat ON bat.entry_id=pl.child_entry_id
WHERE ct.channel_id IN(18,33,43)
ORDER BY bat.title
```

Am I going to have to run a subquery? I'd rather not if I can avoid it but

I'm at a loss as to why adding:

```
GROUP BY ct.entry_id
```

messes things up... :?

Comment: You can't just group by one column and leave the rest as is. You need to group on every column in the result set that you don't want to aggregate by.

Comment: GROUP BY is a good idea, combine it with MIN(author_name). Remember the general group by rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break ties between authors to pick a "winner"; `max()` or `min()` are two easy ways to do this:

```
SELECT
  ct.entry_id AS SKU,
  c.channel_title,
  ct.title,
  ct.status,
  min(bat.title) AS author_title
FROM exp_store_products sp
JOIN exp_channel_titles ct ON ct.entry_id=sp.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channels c ON c.channel_id=ct.channel_id
LEFT JOIN exp_playa_relationships pl ON pl.parent_entry_id=ct.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles bat ON bat.entry_id=pl.child_entry_id
WHERE ct.channel_id IN(18,33,43)
GROUP BY ct.entry_id, c.channel_title, ct.title, ct.status
```

Using `min()` (as here) will give you the alphabetically first name.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ORDER BY min(bat.title)`?

Comment: @thor actually, no need for order by (I left that in from the copy paste of the query). The min() function does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid dealing with grouping/aggregation by moving author-title logic to SELECT part.

This solution is more effective than aggregation if you plan to limit your result set ( pagination, lazy feed ). In this case author title will be resolved for visible rows only.

```
SELECT ct.entry_id AS SKU,
   c.channel_title, ct.title, ct.status,
   (
     SELECT bat.title
     FROM exp_channel_titles bat
     JOIN exp_playa_relationships pl ON bat.entry_id=pl.child_entry_id
     WHERE pl.parent_entry_id=ct.entry_id 
     ORDER BY bat.title
     LIMIT 1
   ) AS author_title
FROM exp_store_products sp
JOIN exp_channel_titles ct ON ct.entry_id=sp.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channels c ON c.channel_id=ct.channel_id
WHERE ct.channel_id IN(18,33,43)
```